# iOS Testing with Instruments - Best Practices

Tags: ios, testing, mobile, instruments

Since I'm developing iOS based applications, I'm also spending much time on getting started with testing applications and debugging performance issues.

After reading the instruments user guide, I'm now able to detect memory leaks, record the current memory size and cpu-usage and much more, which quiet helps a lot!

Now, in order to improve my testing strategy, I'm looking for a kind of bench mark values or standard values for the different instruments (such as cpu- usage, energy consumption, ...). You know what I mean? For example: I have a cpu-usage of 80% over a period of 10 seconds. Is that okay  or should I think about performance optimization? Sure, in case of cpu-usage, it depends on the action that the app does over that period of time (e.g. reloading some data or something like that) but is there any rule of thumb or best practices for that?

I already did a research on the internet and only found a video of the iOS tech talk in london from Michael Jurewitz. In that talk, i figured out the following statements that are properly useful for me:

- Activity Monitor: Can only be used to compare your app's resource usage to other apps
- Allocations: A constantly growing allocations chart is obviously a bad sign for memory leaks. Allocations does not show the real memory size the app uses
- VM Tracker: Show overall memory size; Rule of thumb: more than 100 MB dirty size of an app is far too much
- ...

Now I need some "rules of thumb", especially for the CPU Monitor (where is the boundary between good case and bad case?) and Energy Consumption (Level..?).

Do you have any tips for me or do you know some articles I can read through?

Thanks a lot!

Philipp